# How to put server data to function in modal/pop-up in thymeleaf (java)

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I can't understand one thing.

My case: I have VacationRequests as an object in the Backend (BE).

```
@Data
public class Request {

@Id
private String id;
private LocalDateTime requestedAt;
private LocalDateTime decisionDate;
private RequestType type;
private RequestStatus status;

private String userId;
private String userFirstName;
private String userLastName;
private LocalDate from;
private LocalDate to;
}
```

I send it to the frontend (FE) and show all vacation requests in the table (data from each request from `myActiveRequests` list). User can update vacation request if needed.

Code:

```
  <tbody>
    <tr th:each="request,iter: ${myActiveRequests}">
      <td th:text="${iter.count}" />
      <td th:text="${request.getType()}" />
      <td>
        From:<span th:text="${#temporals.format(request.from, 'dd-MM-yyyy')}"/>
        to: <span th:text="${request.to}"/>
      </td>
      <td th:text="${#temporals.format(request.requestedAt, 'dd-MM-yyyy')}" />
      <td th:text="${request.status.PLANNED.toString()}"/>
      <td><button th:value="${request.id}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#vacationModal" onclick="updateVacation()">Edit</button></td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
```

In the third `<td>` i have vacation data from and to. As you see I have `EDIT` button. So if user decided to change his request, I want him to see pop-up with predefined 'from' and 'to' from third `<td>`.
I created function `updateVacation` which calls after click on `Edit` button, but i don't understand how to send into this function request `id` (yes, it has this property), `from` and `to` value.
in this case i will have possibility to create ajax post call to BE and update existing Vacation reqeust by id.

I thought to put id attribute in html, but there would be 1-2-3-10 requests so id is not a case.

I'm BE guy, not FE, so sorry if this is too weird questions. Just rub my nose in it and I will be happy.

Comment: I'm not a fan of inline code but a quick fix for this is to do `onclick="updateVacation(this)"` and use `function updateVacation(btn) { ... }`. Now you can read `btn.value` to get the id.

Comment: I thought about this. But updateVacation(this) just send me <td> with button, I can't get value of `from` and `to` value of third `td`. and don't have id of request
That's the reason I can't do this.

Comment: You can use `const rowCells = btn.closest('tr').querySelectorAll('td');` to get a list of the `<td>`s in the same row as the button. However this approach uses DOM elements to store data, which isn't good practice. I'd populate the popup using `fetch` and the id to load the data from the server.